# how to multiply array in multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to multiply **quantity value** in multi dimensional array and also get the result based on the quantity

This is the array:

```
$meal_plan[$res['week']][$res2['day']][$res3['meal_plan_type']][$res3['quantity']][]=$res4;
```

This is the loop:

```
foreach ($meal_plan as $week => $dayArr) {
            foreach ($dayArr as $day => $meatTypeArr) {
                $tFat = $tCal = $tKJoules = $tCarb  = $tProt =0;  

                foreach ($meatTypeArr as $mealType => $meals) {
                     foreach ($meals as $mealQuantity => $mealq) {  //quantity loop
                    foreach ($mealq as $meal_id => $meal) {

                        $tFat += $meal['total_fat'];
                        $tCal += $meal['calories'] ;
                        $tKJoules += $meal['kilojoules'] ;
                        $tCarb += $meal['carbs'] ;
                        $tProt += $meal['protien'] ;    
                    }

                }
            }
}
```

This is my array, I want to multiply the value of cabs/ protein/ fat etc with the quantity array. How to do that ?

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Breakfast] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [recepy_id] => 451
                                            [recepy_name] => Egg Omelette
                                            [meal_id] => 1
                                            [total_fat] => 17.7
                                            [calories] => 315
                                            [kilojoules] => 1310
                                            [carbs] => 18.6
                                            [protien] => 18
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [Lunch] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [recepy_id] => 1016
                                            [recepy_name] => Reduced Fat Milk
                                            [meal_id] => 4
                                            [total_fat] => 3
                                            [calories] => 127
                                            [kilojoules] => 530
                                            [carbs] => 15.25
                                            [protien] => 10
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [recepy_id] => 639
                                            [recepy_name] => Custard - Egg
                                            [meal_id] => 4
                                            [total_fat] => 5.2
                                            [calories] => 82
                                            [kilojoules] => 344
                                            [carbs] => 1.7
                                            [protien] => 6
                                        )
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [recepy_id] => 1026
                                            [recepy_name] => Beef Waldorf Salad
                                            [meal_id] => 2
                                            [total_fat] => 11
                                            [calories] => 288
                                            [kilojoules] => 1202
                                            [carbs] => 28
                                            [protien] => 19
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [Snack] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [recepy_id] => 997
                                            [recepy_name] => Avocado -  60g
                                            [meal_id] => 4
                                            [total_fat] => 13
                                            [calories] => 125
                                            [kilojoules] => 522
                                            [carbs] => 0.3
                                            [protien] => 1
                                        )
                                )
                        )   
                )    
        )    
)
```

Comment: A few notes-- first, welcome to SO. I think you need to narrow the scope of what you're asking.  Are you having trouble figuring out multi-dimensional arrays? or are you needing help with calculating the totals. I gave up trying to figure out where breakfast and lunch came from and why they are buried so far in an array.  Also, your code is susceptible to SQL injection.  mysql_query is old, don't use it.  Use mysqli instead, preferably with prepare statements.

Comment: Breakfast/lunch coming from $res3['meal_plan_type'] and same table has the res3['quantity']......i just want protein etc value show accroding to quantity like protein =20 when quantity =1. . .....if quantity = 2 so protein => 20x2= 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it seems you want separate totals per day. So then you would do it like this:

```
foreach ($meal_plan as $week => $dayArr) {
    foreach ($dayArr as $day => $meatTypeArr) {
        $tFat = $tCal = $tKJoules = $tCarb  = $tProt = 0;  
        foreach ($meatTypeArr as $mealType => $meals) {
            foreach ($meals as $mealQuantity => $mealq) {  //quantity loop
                foreach ($mealq as $meal_id => $meal) {
                    // Multiply each with $mealQuantity:
                    $tFat += $mealQuantity * $meal['total_fat'];
                    $tCal += $mealQuantity * $meal['calories'] ;
                    $tKJoules += $mealQuantity * $meal['kilojoules'] ;
                    $tCarb += $mealQuantity * $meal['carbs'] ;
                    $tProt += $mealQuantity * $meal['protien'] ;    
                }
            }
        }
        // Add to result array (a set of totals per day)
        $result[$week][$day] = [
            "total_fat" => $tFat,
            "calories" => $tCal,
            "kilojoules" => $tKJoules,
            "carbs" => $tCarb,
            "protein" => $tProt
        ];
    }
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/806383).

Comment: It was done by mistake. Removed blank array in $mealplan array